# I want to change viewport on pc to mobile view

Tags: viewport

I want to change viewport on pc like a mobile view. I'd like to change it to a viewport of 480 pixels wide(the letters get bigger), which one should I modify?
site is https://www.dorothycard.com/v/sample-classic

Codes below

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a CSS property [`zoom`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/zoom), but it's **non-standard** and you cannot set sized based on container size as far as I know. If you set up everything to be based on `rem`/`em` you could also scale the page by setting the font-size on `html`.

To only affect the desktop view it should be possible to employ a `@media` query.

---

If you just want to test dimensions, that can be done in the browser development tools. Most of them will have a "responsive" mode where the exact dimensions can be specified or known devices can be selected.

E.g. in Chrome it's this button:
[image: chrome dev tools]

In Firefox:
[image: firefox dev tools]